# useRef only gets last values from mapped form antd Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, input, antd, use-ref

I get a bunch of references from an API, I want to insert each Reference with its quantity, I am using antd form useRef
and I get undefined values

```
const formRef =useRef();

const  submitFunction= (values) => {
    
    formRef.current.validateFields().then((values) => {
 
      console.log("Values:", values);
    });

  };
```

```
{reference.map((e, index) => (
        <Form  ref={formRef} 
        initialValues={{
          ["Ref"]: e.reference 
        }}>
          <div>
            <Row style={{ backgroundColor: "darkcyan" }} gutter={8}>
              <Col span={5}>
                <Form.Item   label="Ref" name="Ref" labelCol={{ span: 6 }}>
                  <Input   key={index} defaultValue={e.reference}  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>

              <Col span={8}>
                <Form.Item name="quantity">
                  <InputNumber key={index} />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={8}>
                <Form.Item>
                  <Button onClick={() => submitFunction()}>
                    click me
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </Form>
      ))}
```

referencesList

[image]
 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late to answer the question. It seems that because you have a list of `Form` component and `formRef` is connected to each form, logically the reference value of the forms are replaced one by one in the `formRef` till it gets to the last one. If you want to prevent that you can initialize `formRef` as an empty array like this:

```
const formRef = useRef([]);
```

And define `ref` prop of the `Form` component like so:

```
ref={el => {
   if (el)  formRef.current[index] = el
}}
```

finally change `submitFunction` :

```
const submitFunction = (value) => {
  formRef.current.map(form => {
    form.validateFields().then((values) => {
      console.log("Values:", values);
    });
  })
};
```